# Denying access to my custom module in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I created a custom module in prestashop but I don't know how to handle the access to this module. I didn't find any documentation about it. I know how to do it in symfony but not in prestashop.
I just want to give access to my module to a group of users. Does someone know how to do it or have a link of documentation to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if logged user belongs to the certain group. My example below shows how to check user's default group in a controller. Based on that you can proceed with restricting your module.

```
if ($this->context->customer->isLogged()) {
    $customerGroupId = $this->context->customer->id_default_group;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. So knowing if the user is in the group or not I can render the template or a template access denied? Or is there another cleaner solution?